# Missing map file in latex on Mac OSX

Tags: fonts, pdftex, mac, font-map

I'm trying to compile latex sample file for scientific journal JCAP (https://jcap.sissa.it/jcap/help/JCAP_TeXclass.jsp), but I am always getting following error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 ecti1000

mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ecti1000. mktexpk: perhaps ecti1000 is missing from the map file.

kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

If I understand correctly font ecti1000 is missing from map file. Hence, I tried to check my map file, and I obtained:

```
Map ecti1000.map    enabled /opt/local/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg   (not available)
Map kpathsea.map    enabled /opt/local/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg   (not available
```

Obviously, problem is there. But I was not able to find how to install/reinstall those fonts.

Comment: Try adding the command `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc }§` after the `\documentclass` command.

Comment: Did you install MacTeX or another flavor?

Comment: I am using TexStudio, and this line \userpackage[T1]{fontenc} is already there.

Comment: It looks as though you didn’t install TeX Live using MacTeX or you have more than one distribution installed.